# artery at32f437 + sram, слишком медленно

Tags: c

Работаю с artery at32f437 на голом железе.

Пытаюсь работать с памятью SRAM через интерфейс EXMC (аналог интерфейса FSMC чипов stm32).
Сигнал NWAIT (т.н. wait signal) не использую.
Программный код простейший - последовательное чтение ячеек памяти SRAM, взят из примера библиотеки at32f437 (из \AT32F435_437_Firmware_Library_EN\project\at_start_f437\examples\xmc\sram).
Настройки в принципе просты.

Осциллограф показал, что между последовательными чтениями ячеек SRAM, at32f437 делает чудовищные паузы более 100 тактов.
Никто не сталкивался с этим?